# '{' came as a complete surprise to me

Tags: java, stringtemplate-4

I want to use `org.stringtemplate.v4.*` as template engine for rendering html pages.
However I cant find how to escape open brackets in my file. Templator thinks that it is some expression, while it is just javascript code.

I tried `\{` but this not help - i stil got

```
504:15: invalid character '\'
504:16: '{' came as a complete surprise to me
```

How to escape this? Or what analogs of stringtemplate exist, that can correctly handle html page as input?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Without knowing the framework, have you tried {{?

Answer (score 1):

When I got this error was because I forgot a end sign ($) for a attribute. It should be like this `$attribute.name$`

Reference: http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST/Expressions#Expressions-AttributeReferences

Comment: URL 404s in 2017

Answer (score 0):

Since java is tagged, i would guess you have to also escape `\` since it's a special character in java to may be `\\{`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when I had an unescaped `$` inside some content inside an XML file I was using as a template. Fixed it by using `\$` instead.